# youtube js api, internet explorer(8+, inc. 10) "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'playVideo' "

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

div with the video is initially hidden(with `display: none;`), but iframe seems to be loaded just fine, on press of a button I first change `display: none;` to `display: block;`, then do player(which is the instance of yt player) `player.playVideo()`, nothing unusual, really. But it throws this error.

Logging out `player.playVideo` indeed returns `undefined`.

Logging `player`, returns this

```
{
   "b":{
      "b":{
         "width":1259,
         "height":709,
         "videoId":"videaidhere",
         "playerVars":{
            "autoplay":0,
            "controls":0,
            "showinfo":0,
            "rel":0,
            "modestbranding":1,
            "html5":0,
            "wmode":"transparent"
         }
      },
      "defaults":{
         "host":"http://www.youtube.com",
         "title":"video player",
         "videoId":"",
         "width":640,
         "height":360
      },
      "a":false
   },
   "a":{
      "closure_uid_78774223":2
   },
   "o":{

   },
   "closure_uid_78774223":1,
   "s":1,
   "d":130,
   "u":false,
   "t":[
      {
         "event":"command",
         "func":"addEventListener",
         "args":[
            "onReady"
         ]
      },
      {
         "event":"command",
         "func":"addEventListener",
         "args":[
            "onStateChange"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "g":{
      "a":[
         null,
         "onReady",
         null,
         null,
         "onStateChange",
         null,
         null
      ],
      "b":{
         "onReady":[
            1
         ],
         "onStateChange":[
            4
         ]
      },
      "G":7
   },
   "h":"player",
   "D":{
      "onReady":true,
      "onStateChange":true
   },
   "k":{

   },
   "i":{

   }
}
```

It works on every browser but IEs, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is indeed simply because the div is initially hidden, all you need to do is to hide it some other way, I didn't really have much success with `visibility: hidden;` or `opacity: 0;`, `top: -alot;` along with parent being `overflow: hidden;` did the job.

This piece of code from Harry Roberts could probably do the job as well.

```
/**
 * Hide content off-screen without resorting to `display:none;`, also provide
 * breakpoint specific hidden elements.
 */
@mixin accessibility{
    border:0!important;
    clip:rect(0 0 0 0)!important;
    height:1px!important;
    margin:-1px!important;
    overflow:hidden!important;
    padding:0!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    width:1px!important;
}
```